# Parabola intersection at line of infinity

Tags: geometry

Does a parabola eventually form a sort of ellipse when stretched to infinity along its axis? I am asking because I am trying to intuitively understand the following picture and the fact that the line at infinity is a tangent of parabola:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elipse has $2$ focuses. What would fouces be in that case?

If we imagine point $F$ in infinity along that axis and $G$ is focus of parabola then for every point $P$ on parabola we have $$PF+PG = \infty $$

Here is an explanation for the tangent. Let $\infty _{\ell}$ means point in infinity determined by line $\ell$.

[image]

For every $P$ on a parabola, perpendicular bisector (= MP) for $P'G$ is a tangent on parabola at $P$. So as $P'\to \infty_f $ also $P\to \infty_{axis}$ and $M\to \infty_f$. Now if $P'=\infty _f$ then $MP = \infty_f\infty_{axis}$ = line in infinity.

Comment: Well you did not answer either. Check my first comment on the other answer, that is the actual question. Do the lines meet at infinity or no?

Comment: @MichaelMunta I've made some explanation about tangent. Hope it helps.

Comment: I was asking strictly intuitively, does the parabola close at this tangent point?

Comment: What do you mean by close. Explain in croatian languague.

Comment: Kad bi beskonačno pratio tu parabolu jel se ona u toj crvenoj točci zatvori? Pogledaj sliku na pitanju. Jel ova crvena linija ta parabola? Jel jasnije na što mislim?

Comment: Definitely not, parabola is not a closed curve. It's just a symbolic representation when author want to expalin something regadirng the tangent in infinity

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer. :)

Comment: By the way, I actually just found another question on this and an answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695113/why-does-a-parabola-have-a-single-point-at-infinity . The answer states that in fact the parabola closes. What do you think?

Comment: That is puted in a projective plane where every two line also meet each other. If lines are paralel they meet at point in infinity. So, yes in projective plane we can think as the arms of parabola meet again but not in the sense of Euclidian geometry where circle is closed curve. I would use term closes for circle or ellipse, but not for parabola or hyperbola.

Comment: Maybe I should have stated that my question was in the context of projective plane... My mistake!

Comment: @MichaelMunta Strictly speaking, there is no “line at infinity” on the projective plane and all nondegenerate conics are projectively equivalent. It’s only after singling out some line as the line at infinity (often as a side-effect of choosing a homogeneous coordinate system) that you can distinguish among ellipses, parabolas and hyperbolas.

Comment: @Air back to the answer I linked in the comments. It is explained that this point of a parabola is a double point at the line of infinity, meaning that the parabola intersects itself at that point. I have also read somewhere that double points do not have a unique tangent, so does that mean there are more tangents except the line of infinity?

Answer (score 0):

When talking about weird things like „line at infinity“ it is best to be clear on the spaces one is using.

> **Edit** in a comment to the accepted answer the op has mentioned that the context is the projective plane. What follows is therefore irrelevant. However I feel like the viewpoint I present is interesting enough to not delete my answer. I apologize for potential confusion that arose.

So I guess you are talking about the extension of the polynomial $p:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, x \mapsto x^2$ to the one point compactification $\mathbb R_\infty=\overline{\mathbb R}/\{\pm\infty\} \cong \mathbb S^1$ by letting $p(\infty) = \infty$. The *line at infinity* is the constant map $\ell:\mathbb R_\infty \rightarrow \mathbb R_\infty, x\mapsto\infty$.

Now think of the graph of both $p$ and $\ell$ in $\mathbb R_\infty \times \mathbb R_\infty \cong \mathbb S^1\times\mathbb S^1$, which is the torus. It is hard to describe but not too hard to see that the graph of $p$ forms a closed path around the torus meeting the graph of $\ell$ only once. So in some sense, the graph of $p$ indeed forms a cycle.

Writing $c_0$ for the constant function evaluating to 0 the attached image should illustrate what I mean.
[image: a picture of the graphs embedded in the torus]

Comment: Well, to be clear let's say that we split this parabola at the axis into the left and right curve. If we follow them to the infinity they will meet at this tangent point and close the path?

Comment: @MichaelMunta yes exactly. I have added an image to be more clear about what I mean.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. To me is like asking a doctor if I'm sick and he's starting to explain me math. What is the answer then?

Comment: Can you tell me where I can find more about this notation as a polyomial of a line at infinity?

Comment: @MichaelMunta I tried my best to explain my intuition on what I thought you were asking. Unfortunately I don’t really know sources on how functions $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ act when taking $\infty$ into account. For the isomorphisms $\mathbb R_\infty \cong \mathbb S^1$ and $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1 \cong \mathbb T^2$ I would suggest looking up *stereographic projection* and *construction of the torus*. Wikipedia is good but you will also find this in any book on general topology and/or manifolds.

Comment: @User2020201 I don’t understand your comment. The first paragraph explicitly states that the context of the question is unclear to me, the following gives a context in that the answer to the question is affirmative. I am not a doctor (neither med. nor science), so better don’t ask me about your health status...

Comment: Normally for "line at infinity" one wants to consider the projective plane $\Bbb P^2$, not the one-point compactification of the plane.

Comment: @MJD I don’t really see how projectivity comes more naturally into play here and it was not explicitly stated in the question. So sorry if I used an unorthodox context to explain what I thought was going on.